# PDFSharp Locking Tiff Files

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I'm inserting a TIFF file into a PDF using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/). That process works fine, but it's leaving a lock on the TIFF file. The TIFF file is on a SMB share. I am using the WPF version because the GDI version does not support CMYK TIFFs.

```
var output = new PdfDocument();
var input = PdfReader.Open(template_path, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

var page = input.Pages[0];
output.AddPage(page);
page = output.Pages[0];

var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

var image = XImage.FromFile(tiff_path);

gfx.DrawImage(image, 500, 200, 400, 400);

output.Save(destination_path);
output.Close();
```

Update: Simply doing this leaves the TIFF locked. No document opened or XGraphics or anything.

```
 using (var image = XImage.FromFile(path))
 {}
```

Update: This works, and is what I am going with for now.

```
using (var fsImage = File.Open(tiffPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    var bitmapSource = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapSource.BeginInit();
    bitmapSource.StreamSource = fsImage;
    bitmapSource.EndInit();

    using (var image = XImage.FromBitmapSource(bitmapSource))
    {

    }
}
```

Indecently, this nasty piece of code works also :-)

```
using (var image = XImage.FromFile(tiffPath))
{

}
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: I assume your question is "How do I release this lock?" One suggestion would be to dispose of the image: it might be holding a lock on the file. So, `image.Dispose()`, after you've drawn it.

Comment: I've tried that, image is still locked. Tried disposing the output doc also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With WPF `BitmapSource`, there is no deterministic disposal of the underlying stream, so you can end up with locks for as long as there is a reference.

```
You --> XImage --> BitmapSource --> Stream
```

If you call dispose on the `XImage`, it will release its reference on the `BitmapSource`, which will allow it to be finalized when the GC feels like it.

You can control when the file is closed by providing stream in lieu of a path and closing it explicitly.  Doing so prematurely will cause exceptions in `BitmapSource`, however, so be sure you are not using the `BitmapSource` after you close the stream.

```
using (var fsImage = File.Open(tiff_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    var output = new PdfDocument();
    var input = PdfReader.Open(template_path, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

    var page = input.Pages[0];
    output.AddPage(page);
    page = output.Pages[0];

    var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    var bitmapSource = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapSource.BeginInit();
    bitmapSource.StreamSource = fsImage;
    bitmapSource.EndInit();
    using (var image = XImage.FromBitmapSource(bitmapSource))
    {
        gfx.DrawImage(image, 500, 200, 400, 400);
    }

    output.Save(destination_path);
    output.Close();
}
```

If your image is small enough, you could skip the stream and just use the `BitmapCacheOption` of `OnLoad` to close the source after opening, but this will cause the entire image to be loaded into memory.

Comment: `XImage.FromFile` does not take a stream parameter. Should it? Going to double-check I'm running the latest. I did try wrapping the `DrawImage` in a using but same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  You can use `XImage(BitmapSource)` instead, but you will have to open the bitmap yourself.  See the edit for code.

Comment: There is `XImage.FromStream()` and there is `XImage.FromBitmapSource()`. And `XImage.FromFile()` can be called with a stream, but is marked as obsolete.

Comment: I'm not seeing `XImage.FromStream()` in 1.32-WPF? Neither the `[Obsolete]` method.